# LEGO games for grown-ups?

Tags: lego-games

Are all LEGO Boardgames more or less for children, or are some of them suitable for grown-up, more expert players? (Everybody likes relaxing with a simple game, but are any of the games a bit more challenging?)

Comment: From personal experience (which doesn't quite qualify as an answer), the games I tried left me with a feeling of being a bit too easy, or repetitive, thus having low replay value. Also, the competitive stance of all these games tends to get annoying.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The most obvious answer is probably the [LEGO Heroica](https://web.archive.org/web/20120203073617/http://heroica.lego.com/en-us/Default.aspx) range, especially when played in "Campaign" mode; for more details see our [Heroica tag wiki](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/tags/heroica/info).

There are also a few examples of "Expert" rules that others have come up with, including our very own Joe Wreschnig's set on his dedicated site.

> [Advanced Heroica PDF](https://greygnome.files.wordpress.com/2011/08/advanced-heroica-pdf.pdf) by Jason Glover/GreyGnomeGames ([archived page](https://web.archive.org/web/20120610011213/http://greygnome.com:80/2011/08/20/advanced-heroica-pdf-download/))

Both of these make the ruleset more complicated and can encourage more of a team play than the usual competitive play that my kids make it.

[LEGO Creationary](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=3844-1) is another game where the modelling requirements make it a slightly less child friendly game than some of the others.

Comment: Good to know someone made coop rules for Heroica games (I didn't dare try these yet as I feared I would be disappointed), they sound much more interesting.

Comment: @Joubarc I've not tried the more advanced rules "officially" with my kids yet (4 and 7), although I've taken some of Joe's ideas and others - I've used Joe's Thief changes, and added a variant where the Druid can heal other characters over a certain distance - making it more of a true healer than it currently is. Works nicely when each player has multiple characters too.

Comment: I've played Creationary with adults only and it works well.